# difference between the deprecated Java SDK and current Kotlin SDK for using Rocket chat in Android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rocket.chat, android-studio-3.2

what is the difference between the deprecated Java SDK and current Kotlin SDK for using Rocket chat in Android app?

If we use the Java SDK now, which are the functionalities that are unavailable or has problems?

I want to use it for an android project which is in Java. what problems will I face if I use the DEPRECATED Java SDKs?